# Prevent object dispose inside using block

Tags: c#, winforms, idisposable, objectdisposedexception, litedb

### Workflow:

I have a winform app with two forms, in the 1st form I query a `liteDB` and it manipulates an `IEnumerable<T>` instance **inside a `using` block** with retrieved data.

```
IEnumerable<student> searchResult;
using(var db = new LiteDatabase(@"C:\Temp\MyData.db"))
{
    var col = db.GetCollection<student>("students");
    col.EnsureIndex(x => x.contact.phone);
    searchResult = col.Find(x => x.contact.phone == "123456789");
}
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
Form2.profileData = searchResult.AtElement(index);
```

## Problem:

I then, need to send an element of `searchResult<student>` to 2nd form in order to show user, **as you can see in the last 2 lines of above code.**
But since it's inside `using` block, I get **`System.ObjectDisposedException`**.

## Data types and exception:

### `studentCollection.Find()`:
[image: studentCollection.Find()]
`searchResult`:
[image]
Exception:
[image]
Addition:

What I already though of as possible way is:
Override and nullify existing `dispose()` method then call my own implemented method after I'm done; Which is basically equals to not having a `using` block, except that I don't have to take care of disposing other objects in above `using` block, but only `searchResult<student>`.

> P.S:
> I'm newbie at whole thing, appreciate the help and explanation

Comment: and why not put the `Form2` into the `using`-statement as well? Apart from this your code seems pretty inefficient as you're running the query three times: once within `EnsureIndex`, once within `Find` and once for `AtElement`. You should meterialize the collection, e.g. by calling `ToList`.

Comment: You have `var myIList = ...` inside the `using` block and `IList<student> myIList;` outside.

Comment: Overriding `Dispose` by doing nothing is a really bad idea. Either there **is** something to be disposed or not. In the first case you should implement `IDisposable` apropriately, in the latter not. Implementing it by an empty function is counter-intuitive. It implies: there's something to be disposed here - no, wait, it's not.

Comment: remove var i think it will work

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain It's just a simplification, actually after `myIList` manipulated, there is a `foreach` for a `dataGridView` which has a buttonCell and when user clicks on each row's button, 2nd form shows up with the full profile (In `AtElement(index)`, the index is rowID of DGV) that way I have to do it inside `using` too!

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain For edited comment, `EnsureIndex` makes an index of a field or do nothing if already exists according to official website example. And as for `AtElement`, I'm newbie, does linq query it again this way and `ToList` doesn't? Isn't the giving list also `IDispoable' so will be disposed?

Comment: @Jimi tnx for mentioning, fixed

Comment: `myIList = col.Find(...).ToList();`

Comment: @NegiRox code edited and fixed, and sadly it won't bcs problem is that it's inside `using` block and will be disposed

Comment: @Jimi `ToList` gives non-IDisposable object? Otherwise it'll be disposed too as long as being inside `using` ?

Comment: I assume, from the code, that `db.GetCollection<student>()` returns a collection of class objects (of Type `student`). Or `col.Find()` does. In this case, the elements in the collection are not disposed. You're disposing of the `LiteDatabase` object there, when the collection it generates is materialized, you won't gest *object disposed* exceptions -- If this is not the case, then write down the returned Type.

Comment: @Jimi I apologize, since It's my first practical project I miscalled `IEnumerable<>` as `IList<>`. I looked in the code now and edited. gonna try my luck with `ToList()` rn.

Comment: @Shahaboddin: `ToList()` will *materialize* the results while the database connection is still active. So long as you've got all the data out, it should be fine. Note that a `using` statement doesn't dispose of anything other than the value in the "header" of the statement. So no, it's not going to try to dispose a `List<T>`.

Comment: As a note, you keep on changing the code in the question, so a lot of comments become mute. Please, don't do that. Edit the question to present a *work in progress* (a sequence of tests and their different results), if necessary.

Comment: @Jimi I understand and sorry for this behavior.  it's finalized by now and screenshots added. Wont happen again

Comment: @Jimi declared as `student[] searchResult` and in order to avoid that triple query @MakePeaceGreatAgain said used `ToArray()` instead of `ToList()`, since the size is fixed this avoid `linq ElementAt()`. Please kindly write your comment as answer so I can mark it. tnx for dealing with my messy question editing and comments; learned a lot from ur kind behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familliar with LiteDb, but I would assume it returns a proxy object for the database. So when the database is disposed, the proxy-object is no longer usable.

The simple method to avoid the problem is to add `.ToList()` after the `.Find(...)`. This will convert the proxy-list to an actual `List<T>` in memory, and it can be used after the database is disposed. It is possible that the `student` objects inside the list are *also* proxies, and if that is the case this will fail.

If that is the case you either need to find some way to make the database return real, non-proxy objects, or extend the lifetime of the database to be longer than that of your form, for example

```
IList<student> myIList;
using(var db = new LiteDatabase(@"C:\Temp\MyData.db"))
{
    var col = db.GetCollection<student>("students");
    col.EnsureIndex(x => x.contact.phone);
    myIList = col.Find(x => x.contact.phone == "123456789");
    using(var frm2 = new Form2()){
       frm2.profileData = myIList.AtElement(index);
       frm2.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

Note the usage of `.ShowDialog`, this will block until the second form has been closed. That is not strictly necessary, but it makes it much easier to manage the lifetime of the database.

Comment: @JonasH, I understand you meant `.ToList()`, not `.ToString()`

Comment: @Gian Paolo Yes, Oups.

Comment: `student` is simple **poco class** forms the LiteDB document written by myself. Form2 shows full details on a student object, like the name says `profileData` this why DB query should be done as form2 shows so user can query new student and open profiles at same. `ToList()` does the trick for proxy object, tnx

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the element before exiting the using block.

```
using(var db = new LiteDatabase(@"C:\Temp\MyData.db"))
{
    var col = db.GetCollection<student>("students");
    col.EnsureIndex(x => x.contact.phone);
    var searchResult = col.Find(x => x.contact.phone == "123456789");
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    Form2.profileData = searchResult.AtElement(index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for effort, but as said in the comments up there, it has to be used elsewhere in 2nd form.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You assign it here. Then the second form can use it. later What am I missing? Are you saying that the item you are retrieving  from the search result stops working in some way after the using block exits? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I mean I need the process to be done (i.e: reach to the end of `using` block) so user can query another search (I should mention that like did in comments up there, that I have a `dataGridView` after the `using` block which I render `searchResult` in it, and it has a `ButtonCell` which cause the 2nd form to be shown); plus the second form shouldnt get closed after process is done, so we can have multiple student's profile open.

Comment: I am trying to understand but to me it sounds like that has nothing to do with anything. *Obtain* the instance within the using block; *use* it outside the using block, or anywhere else you want. What’s the problem?  Once you have the instance assigned to a variable, you don’t need the search results anymore.